# QWidget when setMaximumSize Maximize button doesn't work

Tags: qt, qwidget, qscrollarea

I have a QWidget which have an horizontal layout which holds a QScrollArea.
When I add a widget to the QScrollArea, I change the maximum size for the container QWidget with:

```
this->setMaximumSize(newWidget->maximumWidth(), newWidget->maximumHeight());
```

The maximum size is well changed but the maximize button doesn't work anymore. I can change the size of the widget with the mouse, but not with the maximize button.

If I set the maximum size with a higher value, for example:

```
this->setMaximumSize(newWidget->maximumWidth() * 2, newWidget->maximumHeight() * 2);
```

The maximize button works well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `QWidget` top-level?  Can you resize it to fill the screen, or does it stop at maximum size you set?

Comment: Yes, It's top-level. And it stops at the maximum size set, but only when the mouse is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the maximum size to be less than that of your desktop size.  So when you try to maximise the widget, you are asking the widget to go beyond the maximum size you set it - so it ignores you.

Presumably `newWidget->maximumWidth() * 2` works because that figure is larger than your desktop size.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the desktop width is 1280 and I want that the maximum width for my window to be 889. So, if the current size of my window is 300, can't i use the maximize button to set the width to 889?

Comment: No, maximisation of windows is not 'set it to the biggest size it will go', it is a desktop environment state which you have effectively disabled by stopping the window growing large enough to dock with the screen edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot.One more thing, do you have any idea for solving my problem?.

Comment: Why are you limiting the window size?  The whole point of the scroll area is to allow an object of any size to fit in the window.  The other alternative is to use the scroll area in a `QDialog` so you can hide the maximise button.

Comment: I limit the window size because I don't want that the window to be higher than the size it has.